# Retrieving data set using jQuery.data()

Tags: jquery

I set some data to a div on the first click using jQuery.data().On the second click, when I try to retrieve it, it gives me 'undefined'. Any idea where I am wrong?

[image]

Please see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinayan/mopjLn7p/27/)

```
<div class="player forward playerposition">
    <input type="button" class="addplayer addforward" value="+" />
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.addplayer', storeData);
    $(document).on('click', '.removeplayer', deletedata);
});

function storeData() {
    var div = $(this);
    $.data(div, 'testdata', {
        'Name': 'Ronaldo'
    });
    var data = $.data(div, 'testdata');
    console.log(data);
    div.val('x');
    div.removeClass('addplayer');
    div.addClass('removeplayer');
}

function deletedata() {
    var div = $(this);
    var data = $.data(div, 'testdata');
    console.log(data);
    div.removeData(div, 'testdata');
    div.val('+');
    div.removeClass('removeplayer');
    div.addClass('addplayer');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) api expects a dom element as its first param, not a jQuery object

```
var data = $.data(this, 'testdata');
```

Also [removeData()](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/) expects the key to be removed as its first param

```
div.removeData('testdata');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vqsq9d2s/)

---

Another way is to use the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method of the jQuery object like

```
div.data('testdata', {
    'Name': 'Ronaldo'
});
var data = div.data('testdata');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vqsq9d2s/2/)

Answer (score 1):

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(document).on('click', '#btn',function(){
        var thisObject=$(this);
        if(thisObject.hasClass("addplayer"))
        {
            $.data( thisObject[0], "testdata", {
                Name: "Ronaldo"
            });
            var dataName = $.data(thisObject[0], 'testdata').Name;
            console.log(dataName);
            thisObject.val('x').removeClass('addplayer').addClass('removeplayer');       
        }
        else
        {
            var dataName = $.data(thisObject[0], 'testdata').Name;
            console.log(dataName);
            $.removeData(thisObject[0], 'testdata');
            thisObject.val('+').removeClass('removeplayer').addClass('addplayer');  
        }  
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/psxnd2mn/1/)